# Any examples where a classifier predicts an "other"?

Tags: classification

I have a dataset with multiple categories but also with a catch all other category. For example,

> Category | Count
>   A|10
>   B|12
>   C|4
>   Other|5

So in this case I have three categories where I have human classified results, but I also have 5 where the humans were uncertain.

I would like to train a model with only the data from A,B, and C, and then run that model on Category other to see if I can classify those. However not all of rows in category other belong in categories A,B and C and should still stay in category other.

My dilemma is if I train the model with only data A,B, and C my model can only predict A,B and C. If I train my model with other, I'm introducing known noise into the learning process and I'm fairly certain that won't help my model.

How can I train my model on only the categories I'm "sure" (A,B,C) about, run it on unclassified rows (Other), but still have it return other if it's unsure? I'm thinking model. Perhaps something like a Naive Bayes model with probability cutoffs for certainty?

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm trying to deal with somethign similar.